# Criar uma sequência de dias uteis no R

Tags: r, funções, data.frame

Eu tenho um data frame as seguintes colunas:

Data (Apenas dias da semana e sem feriados, de vários anos)
Mês
Ano
...
Quero criar uma sequência de dias úteis. Então queria uma função que lesse o menor dia do primeiro mês e o maior dia do primeiro mês e colocasse uma sequência de 1 até o final. E repetir isso para todos os meses da minha base de dados.

Alguma ideia??

Answer (score 3):

Use o pacote `bizdays` do Wilson Freitas

```
# install.packages('bizdays')
bizdays::bizseq('2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', cal = "Brazil/ANBIMA")

#> [1] "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03" "2017-01-04" "2017-01-05" "2017-01-06"
#> [6] "2017-01-09" "2017-01-10" "2017-01-11" "2017-01-12" "2017-01-13"
#>[11] "2017-01-16" "2017-01-17" "2017-01-18" "2017-01-19" "2017-01-20"
#>[16] "2017-01-23" "2017-01-24" "2017-01-25" "2017-01-26" "2017-01-27"
#>[21] "2017-01-30" "2017-01-31"
```

Você pode ajustar opções de calendário olhando primeiro o help dessa função.